# Encountering "Some of your feature flags are not valid. Please navigate to Advanced Edit for more details." error in App Configuration

Tags: filter, azure-cli, azure-app-configuration, azure-feature-manager

Trying to add new user in Microsoft.Targeting filter, but getting error: "Some of your feature flags are not valid. Please navigate to Advanced Edit for more details."
[image]

Advanced Edit output using my script

[image]

Anticipated Result (The expected output should resemble the screenshot provided below):

[image]

Az Cli Command :

```
az appconfig feature filter update --connection-string <<Endpoint Connection String here>> --feature featureA --filter-name Microsoft.Targeting --filter-parameters '"\"Audience\": {\"Users\": [\"user1\",\"user2\",\"user3\"],\"Groups\": [],\"DefaultRolloutPercentage\": 50}}"'
```

Unable to read Json file data and pass those values to --function-parameters value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for adding filter parameters is in the form `parameterName=value`. If the "value" is JSON, then it must be escaped. More information on this can be found in the command documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appconfig/feature/filter?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appconfig-feature-filter-update-optional-parameters).

So the command would work as expected if rewritten as follows:

```
az appconfig feature filter update --connection-string <<Endpoint Connection String here>> --feature featureA --filter-name Microsoft.Targeting  --filter-parameters 'Audience={\"Users\": [\"user1\",\"user2\",\"user3\"],\"Groups\": [],\"DefaultRolloutPercentage\": 50}'
```

I hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Albert 
Getting below error when I try to execute above formatted command
This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
Filter parameter value must be a JSON escaped string. "{\"Users\": [\"user1\",\"user2\",\"user3\"],\"Groups\": [],\"DefaultRolloutPercentage\": 50}" is not a valid JSON object.

Comment: are you on linux / windows / mac ? escaping is abit different depending on the OS

Comment: using bash this synthax works for me `--filter-parameters Audience='{"DefaultRolloutPercentage":50,"Users":["user1","user2"],"Groups":[]}'`

Comment: @albert-ofori, your synthax is working with powershell tho :-)

Comment: Below command is working fine for me in Azure Portal Bash

az appconfig feature filter update --connection-string <<ConnectionString>> --feature featureA --filter-name Microsoft.Targeting --filter-parameters "{\"Audience\":{\"Users\":[\"user1\",\"user2\",\"user3\"],\"Groups\":[],\"DefaultRolloutPercentage\":50}}"

Is there a way to append a new user to an existing JSON configuration without modifying the entire JSON structure? Whether through Azure CLI or an alternative PowerShell approach, I'd appreciate guidance on achieving this specific modification.

Comment: @Thomas, If there is a PowerShell document specifically for automating this particular feature, could you please share the document with me?

Comment: so did you manage to get it working ?

Comment: Certainly, the script above is effective for my needs. However, the current requirement is to append a new user instead of updating the entire JSON.